# Configure Microsoft.Owin.Logging.ILogger

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, owin

How do I configure my `ILogger` to write to a different location? I would like to write my logs to `C:\Logs\MyLogFile.log`.

I am setting my custom `LoggerFactory` like so:

```
app.Properties["server.LoggerFactory"] = new MyCustomLoggerFactory();
```

`MyCustomLoggerFactory` looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomLoggerFactory: ILoggerFactory
{
    public ILogger Create(string name)
    {
        return new CustomLogger();
    }
}
```

Then `ICustomLogger` interface and `CustomLogger` class look like this:

```
public interface ICustomLogger : ILogger
{

}

public class CustomLogger : ICustomLogger 
{
    public bool WriteCore(TraceEventType eventType, int eventId, object state, 
        Exception exception, Func<object, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Dont use this one dummy");
    }
}
```

Is there no way to set the LogLevel or Url where the log file gets written? Ideally I would like to also use log4net for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a log4net implementation for in your custom logger, you have to use the TraceEventType to determine the logging level:

```
public class CustomLogger : ICustomLogger 
{
    public bool WriteCore(TraceEventType eventType, int eventId, object state, 
        Exception exception, Func<object, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("myowinlogger");
        switch (eventType){
            case(TraceEventType.Critical): 
            {
                logger.Fatal(...);
            }
            ....

    }
}
```

Make sure you have a configure and you can make a log4net configuration to write to a specific location or appender.